# D3.js: Understanding Zoom in terms of svg

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, zooming

I have been looking into this d3.js block [Timeline with Zoom](http://bl.ocks.org/bunkat/2338034). However, I am not able to figure out how the zoom function is actually implemented. Could somebody help me understand?

Answer (score 8):

Frankly, there is no zoom happening.

```
var brush = d3.svg.brush()
                    .x(x)
                    .on("brush", display);//this calls display function on brush event drag.
```

Inside display function.

```
        minExtent = brush.extent()[0],//this give the brush extent min
        maxExtent = brush.extent()[1],//this give the brush extent max
```

Based on the max and min of the brush filter the data:

```
visItems = items.filter(function(d) {return d.start < maxExtent && d.end > minExtent;});
```

Reset the domain with the brush's max and min.

```
x1.domain([minExtent, maxExtent]);
```

Select all rectangles in the upper area not having the brush associate data to the DOM.
update it with the new scale values

```
    rects = itemRects.selectAll("rect")
            .data(visItems, function(d) { return d.id; })
        .attr("x", function(d) {return x1(d.start);})
        .attr("width", function(d) {return x1(d.end) - x1(d.start);});
```

create any new rectangles if the data is present but DOM is not present.

```
    rects.enter().append("rect")
        .attr("class", function(d) {return "miniItem" + d.lane;})
        .attr("x", function(d) {return x1(d.start);})
        .attr("y", function(d) {return y1(d.lane) + 10;})
        .attr("width", function(d) {return x1(d.end) - x1(d.start);})
        .attr("height", function(d) {return .8 * y1(1);});
```

Remove all the rectangle outsside the brush extent or not in the filtered item list `visItems`

```
    rects.exit().remove();
```

Exactly the same for labels as done for rectangles above.

Hope this clears all your doubts.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure but I think this is just a trick with D3 scales.

What happens is that it gets the selection below (which is a projection a 100% of with from time 0 to time 100) and plots into a new scale from time 50 to time 80 with the same width.

This will make the scale change in a way that looks like you zoomed on that time moment in time.